# Geoserver CSW Header GML namespace missing

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, geoserver

I set up an own XML-tree for the CSW service in geoserver. Therefore I'm also using the CSW-ISO plugin and the metadata plugin so that there is a metadata tab where you configure your layer.

The problem is, that when I do a request with "GetRecordById" there is the gml-namespace missing in the header of the CSW-response from the geoserver. That's why there "null" e.g. when I set a temporal extent:

```
     <gmd:temporalElement>
          <gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
            <gmd:extent>
              <null:TimePeriod null:id="timeperiod">
                <null:beginPosition>2021-09-28</null:beginPosition>
                <null:endPosition>2021-09-30</null:endPosition>
              </null:TimePeriod>
            </gmd:extent>
          </gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
        </gmd:temporalElement>
```

The header looks like:

```
<csw:GetRecordByIdResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/apiso/1.0" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gfc="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gfc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 https://localhost:8443/geoserver/schemas/csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd">
```

The request link looks like:

```
https://localhost:8443/geoserver/csw?service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetRecordById&typeNames=gmd:MD_Metadata&elementsetname=full&outputschema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&id=geo:schule
```

..and if I do the request "GetCapabilities" there is addtional  " xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" " in the header.

Is it possible to configure the header of the csw-response somewhere?

The only good idea I have is that there is a bug in the CSW-ISO plugin because in the github repository I of the CSW-ISO plugin I found folders which look like the namespaces (gco, gmd, gmx) but gml is missing.

By the way, the part in the MD-Metadata.properties is:

```
identificationInfo.MD_DataIdentification.extent.EX_Extent.temporalElement.EX_TemporalExtent.extent.TimePeriod.@id=if_then_else(isNull("metadata.custom.data-valid-date/start-date"), "Expression/NIL", 'timeperiod')
identificationInfo.MD_DataIdentification.extent.EX_Extent.temporalElement.EX_TemporalExtent.extent.TimePeriod.beginPosition=if_then_else(isNull("metadata.custom.data-valid-date/start-date"), "Expression/NIL", dateFormat('YYYY-MM-dd', "metadata.custom.data-valid-date/start-date"))
identificationInfo.MD_DataIdentification.extent.EX_Extent.temporalElement.EX_TemporalExtent.extent.TimePeriod.beginPosition.@indeterminatePosition=if_then_else(isNull("metadata.custom.data-valid-date/end-date"), "Expression/NIL", if_then_else(isNull("metadata.custom.data-valid-date/start-date"), 'unknown', "Expression/NIL"))
identificationInfo.MD_DataIdentification.extent.EX_Extent.temporalElement.EX_TemporalExtent.extent.TimePeriod.endPosition=if_then_else(isNull("metadata.custom.data-valid-date/end-date"), "Expression/NIL", dateFormat('YYYY-MM-dd', "metadata.custom.data-valid-date/end-date"))
identificationInfo.MD_DataIdentification.extent.EX_Extent.temporalElement.EX_TemporalExtent.extent.TimePeriod.endPosition.@indeterminatePosition=if_then_else(isNull("metadata.custom.data-valid-date/start-date"), "Expression/NIL", if_then_else(isNull("metadata.custom.data-valid-date/end-date"), 'unknown', "Expression/NIL"))
```

..and in the part in teh metadata-ui.yaml is:

```
attributes:
 - key: data-valid-date
     fieldType: COMPLEX
     typename: date-range

types:

- typename: date-range
    attributes:
      - key: start-date
        fieldType: DATE
      - key: end-date
        fieldType: DATE
```

Comment: Hello, since I updated to geoserver 2.20.1 it works with the gml namespace. But there is still the srv-namespace missing in the header ( xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" ...is still not there.)

Comment: If it helps, the x-path confiugred in the MD_Metadata.properties should look like this: 

identificationInfo.SV_ServiceIdentification.serviceType.LocalName.@codeSpace=
identificationInfo.SV_ServiceIdentification.serviceTypeVersion.CharacterString=
identificationInfo.SV_ServiceIdentification.couplingType.SV_CouplingType@codeList=
identificationInfo.SV_ServiceIdentification.containsOperations.SV_OperationMetadata.operationName.CharacterString=
identificationInfo.SV_ServiceIdentification.operatesOn.@href=